# Click on custom item with butterknife android

Tags: android, butterknife

I want to add click to my custom item:

```
public class ContactItem extends FrameLayout {

    @BindView(R.id.itemHeader)
    TextView textLabel;
    @BindView(R.id.itemValue)
    TextView textValue;
    @BindView(R.id.imageIcon)
    ImageView icon;
    @BindView(R.id.mainLayout)
    RelativeLayout mainLayout;

    private String label = null;

    public ContactItem(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init(context, null);
    }

    public ContactItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public ContactItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                    R.styleable.textLabel);

            label = a.getString(R.styleable.textLabel_text_attr);

        }

        addView(inflate(context, R.layout.item_contact, null));

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

    }

    public TextView getTextLabel() {
         return  textLabel;
    }

    public TextView getTextValue(){
        return textValue;
    }

    public ImageView getIcon(){
        return icon;
    }

    public void setTextLabelText(int text){
        textLabel.setText(text);
    }

    public void setTextValueText(String text){
        textValue.setText(text);
    }

    public void setIconRes(int res){
        icon.setImageResource(res);
    }

}
```

In my activity I add few items this type.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/color_white">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@color/background"/>

        <views.items.ContactItem
            android:id="@+id/contactTelefon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"/>
        <views.items.ContactItem
            android:id="@+id/contactEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

now, If I click on item contactEmail I want to send email and if contactTelefon I want to make a call. I have functions but onClick doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
@OnClick(R.id.contactTelefon)
public void clickOnCall(){
   presenter.callFunction());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of it's an issue with ButterKnife, but you could try adding `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to your `ContactItem`. The idea behind this is that your top layout is consuming the click event before the child layout gets the very same event.

Another approach would be to add the clicklistener to the LinearLayout e.g.

```
@OnClick(R.id.linearLayout)
public void clickOnCall(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.contactTelefon:
       presenter.callFunction()); break;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should perform `ButterKnife.bind()` on the parent view that hosts your `ContactItem`. The `bind()` within your custom class is a different binding.

So, if this is an activity, put `ButterKnife.bind(this)` in that activity, and thereafter your `@OnClick()` would work as expected.